# Java FX Interface Lazy loading

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, lazy-loading, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm building an application using JavaFX and noticed a unpleasant behavior (maybe a feature)

When the app launches and i start interacting with ui components (buttons specialli) the app reactivity is somehow slow, for example the buttons doesn't perform the click on time etc..

But once i use it enough (interacting with some ui components) it starts to act normal and reactive.

I guess there's something to do with lazy memory allocation or something like this. I've tried to start the JVM with 256mb using `-Xms256m` but still the same problem.

In an ordinary computer, something like that doesn't really bother, but my program is running in a Raspberry Pi 3 B Model, which is in fact annoying.

Any idea about such behavior ?

Comment: Are you actually using [tag:javafx-2] (as you've tagged)? If so, what if you try a more recent version (e.g. JavaFX 13)?

Comment: is it sure that the UI thread is not loaded with something that causes a delay in event processing?

Comment: Sorry i'm using javafx which comes with jdk8.. i'm using jfoenix which works under java 8 or 9 .... and no the ui thread isn't loaded with something else since as i said after some time of using the app it became fluid and reactive ... i'll change my UI and use javafx 13 and will check if the problems remains same